# Why array value is giving 0?

Tags: php

I am reading a whole bunch of data from my users and adding them as associative arrays to be able to join the data. the following gives me the correct arrays values but then I get 0 as a result.

```
<?php
    $userID = array();
    $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
      $gender = 'sesso';
      $single = true;
      $the_user_id = $user->ID;
      array_push($userID, $the_user_id);
      $myUsers = $user->user_description;
      $user_sex = get_user_meta( $the_user_id, $gender, $single ); 
      $users[$user->ID] = array( "description" => $myUsers  , "gender" => $user_sex ); 
    }
    $roles = array();
    foreach($users as $id => $values){
        $temp_roles = explode(',', $values['description']);
        foreach($temp_roles as $k => $v){
          $roles[trim($v)][$values['gender']][] = true;
        }
    }

    ?>
  <ul class="margin-top-20">
    <?php
      foreach($roles as $skill => $genderB) {
          $males = count($genderB['male']);
          $females = count($genderB['female']);
          $total = $males + $females;
          echo $females;
          echo "<li>We have ".$total." ".$skill." teachers, ".$males." males, ".$females." females</li>";
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
```

I get `0` if I do `echo $females;` and the strings all get `0` as values

> We have 0 francese teachers, 0 males, 0 females

if I do `print_r($users[$user->ID] );` right at the end of the first foreach, i get the right result tho

```
Array ( [description] => francese, chimica, fisica, scienze [gender] => Array ( [0] => maschio ) ) Array ( [description] => inglese, fisica, chimica, spagnolo [gender] => Array ( [0] => maschio ) ) Array ( [description] => francese, fisica, italiano [gender] => Array ( [0] => femmina ) )
```

And if I do `print_r($roles);` at the end of the second foreach i get only the roles values but not the gender

```
Array ( [francese] => Array ( ) [chimica] => Array ( ) [fisica] => Array ( ) [scienze] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [francese] => Array ( ) [chimica] => Array ( ) [fisica] => Array ( ) [scienze] => Array ( ) [inglese] => Array ( ) [spagnolo] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [francese] => Array ( ) [chimica] => Array ( ) [fisica] => Array ( ) [scienze] => Array ( ) [inglese] => Array ( ) [spagnolo] => Array ( ) [italiano] => Array ( )
```

The again if I do `print_r($temp_roles);` at the end of the second foreach i get

```
Array ( [0] => francese [1] => chimica [2] => fisica [3] => scienze ) Array ( [0] => inglese [1] => fisica [2] => chimica [3] => spagnolo ) Array ( [0] => francese [1] => fisica [2] => italiano )
```

I don't understand why I am getting 0 values for all of them at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data the gender is defined by `femmina` and `maschio`. In your code you check for `female` and `male`.

The other problem I detected is that you do not have to have both male and female teachers. If you turn your error reporting on, with this code you will get

`Undefined index: female` (or male)

if there are no females. You can work arround it by `$females = isset($genderB['female']) ? count(genderB['female']): 0;`. Or by "full" if statement of course.

Comment: oh please i can't believe it! You have no idea how many hours I spent on this and it was a stupid mistake! Thank you so much, you've made my day!

Comment: about that error, it could happen with males too i guess, will i have to insert the isset even for the males?

Comment: is it written right? $females = isset($genderB['female']) ? count(genderB['femaile']: 0 or is it missing a )?

Comment: @RobertoMarras It is was missing the bracket `)`. I edited it in. Thanks.